# v-for with child object

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs3

Have been trying for a while to make a `v-for` list on the child elements `{song: "xxx"}` object in songs?

```js
export const data = [
{id: "1", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "2", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "3", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "4", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "5", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "6", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "7", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "8", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "9", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "10", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "11", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "12", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "13", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "14", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "15", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "16", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "17", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
```

This is my try, it does not work! (data is the variable where the parent object is stored.

```
 <div class="button" v-for="item in data.songs.song" :key="item.id">
     {{ item.songs }}
   </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: loop over `data.songs`, not `data.songs.song`, then its `item.song` not `item.songs`

Comment: also you use `:key="item.id"` like as if item is the whole object, is the object you have shown on its own or in an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like following snippet:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      albums: [
{id: "1", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "2", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "3", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "4", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "5", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "6", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "7", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "8", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "9", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "10", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "11", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "12", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "13", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "14", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "15", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "16", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
{id: "17", albumname: "xx", artist: "xxxx", dateadded: "xxxx", route: "xxxx", songs: [{ song : 'check2.1' }, { song : 'check2.2' }]},
      ]
    }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div v-for="album in albums" :key="album.id">
    <div class="button" v-for="(item, i) in album.songs" :key="i">
      {{ item.song }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nikola,

Thank you.
I need to get all of the "song" out of each entry. Your code snippet seems to only work when there is one entry. have edited the above code to give you an idea of my code. thanks

Comment: @Web Dev hey mate, check now pls. I updated my answer

Comment: You mean to sort songs ? If that's the case then you need to create computed property and sort your data.

Comment: How would I go about doing that... sorry to drive you mad!

Comment: Can you pls create another question with little sortable data (do you want to sort by song number, song name...) ?